# NameError ao inserir o valor lido pela função input

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou rodando a versão 2.7 de Python:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
```

Quando tento rodar essa [linha de código](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp):

```
x = input('Enter your name:')
print('Hello, ' + x)
```

Tenho o seguinte erro:

```
$ python index.py
Enter your name:acb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 1, in <module>
    x = input('Enter your name:')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'acb' is not defined
```

Alguem sabe como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está utilizando a função `input` no **Python 2.7** sem saber, aparentemente, como ela funciona.

Nesta versão, a função `input` irá avaliar a entrada como um código Python. Se você digitar "Generic" e não existir o objeto `Generic` no contexto, dará o erro de nome, como no seu exemplo.

Veja este exemplo:

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 7

nome = input('Seu nome (digite a, b ou c): ')
print('Seja bem-vindo, ', nome)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FarawayDirtyPentagon)</sup>

Se você entrar com os valores `a`, `b` ou `c` no `input`, o resultado será algo como `Seja bem-vindo, 5`, pois ele avaliará a entrada `a` para o objeto de mesmo nome.

Assim, se precisas manter-se na versão 2.7 do Python, utilize a função `raw_input`, ou, se possível, migre para uma versão mais nova do Python - a mais atual no momento é a 3.7.

Comment: o seu codigo deu certo. vou atualizar.

Comment: sim... eu so estava esperando o tempo mínimo de 7 min. Vc respodeu antes.